# how to link static cells to Outlet/Actions - E.G tap the call cell to call the number

Tags: uitableview, nsstring, uiapplication

The code I have. By the way, I can't get Call to work and Website does not open either!

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString *urlToOpen = @"";
if( indexPath.section == 0 ){
    // call number
    urlToOpen = @"tel:442074036933";
} else if( indexPath.section == 1 ){
    // open website
    urlToOpen = @"http://www.designmuseum.org";
} else {
    // open address

    urlToOpen = @"http://maps.apple.com/maps?daddr=Design+Museum+London";
}
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlToOpen]];
NSString *destinationAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@+%@+%@",
                                [address street],
                                [address city],
                                [address country]];

NSString *sourceAddress = [LocalizedCurrentLocation currentLocationStringForCurrentLanguage];

NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.apple.com/maps?saddr=%@&daddr=%@",
                 [sourceAddress stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
                 [destinationAddress stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

I need to add destination address which for my App is = 28 Shad Thames, London, United Kingdom. Which format to write it in? because I cant get it to work and really need to sort this problem of my app real quick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create outlets for each cell.

Is your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method called?

Then you could just do:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *urlToOpen = @"";
    if( indexPath.section == 0 ){
        // call number
        urlToOpen = @"tel:12125551212";
    } else if( indexPath.section == 1 ){
        // open website
        urlToOpen = @"http://www.google.nl";
    } else {
        // open address
            NSString *destinationAddress = @"Amsterdam";

            Class itemClass = [MKMapItem class];
            if (itemClass && [itemClass respondsToSelector:@selector(openMapsWithItems:launchOptions:)]) {

                CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
                [geocoder geocodeAddressString:destinationAddress completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
                    if([placemarks count] > 0) {

                        MKPlacemark *placeMark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithPlacemark:[placemarks objectAtIndex:0]];

                        MKMapItem *mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc]initWithPlacemark:placeMark];

                        MKMapItem *mapItem2 = [MKMapItem mapItemForCurrentLocation];


                        NSArray *mapItems = @[mapItem, mapItem2];

                        NSDictionary *options = @{
                                        MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving,
                                        MKLaunchOptionsMapTypeKey:
                                        [NSNumber numberWithInteger:MKMapTypeStandard],
                                        MKLaunchOptionsShowsTrafficKey:@YES
                        };

                        [MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:mapItems launchOptions:options];

                    } else {
                        //error nothing found
                    }
                }];
                return;
            } else {

                NSString *sourceAddress = [LocalizedCurrentLocation currentLocationStringForCurrentLanguage];

                urlToOpen = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%@&daddr=%@",
                             [sourceAddress stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
                             [destinationAddress stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            }
    }
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlToOpen]];
}
```

indexPath.section could also be indexPath.row, depending on how you made the tableView.

**Edit:**
I have added the 'Get Directions' part. This checks if it is ios5 or ios6.

For ios5 I use the LocalizedCurrentLocation from this post http://www.martip.net/blog/localized-current-location-string-for-iphone-apps

For ios6 I use the CLGeocoder to get the placemark and then open the map with it and the current location.

Remember to add CoreLocation.framework and MapKit.framework

Comment: need 15 reputation which i dont have unfortunately, 1 last question, this implementation opens maps app, is there no way to do it in my app itself rather than launching maps app

Comment: It is possible, but you can't make the 'get directions' part. You can only show the location and the destination without the line and navigation etc. You would have to create a mapView. Here is a tutorial http://prassan-warrior.blogspot.dk/2012/11/apple-maps-on-iphone-with-mapkit-and.html

Comment: i got something similar, in my app 1 of my tabs is a mapview, which shows a place mark to 'design museum london' with disclosure button i wanted to implement the same thing maps app does where it shows information + get directions button, but wanted do it all within mapview of my app.

Comment: That is not easy to accomplish. Here is a start on maps http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_Maps_on_the_iPhone_with_MapKit_and_the_MKMapView_Class

Comment: think I will stick with it opening the maps app although ideally would like it within my own app. its basically everything you helped me with just but just without launching maps

Comment: 1 more thing, you wouldnt happen to know how to animate a zoom to location or placemark pin? when I open my mapview it drops pin at a location, but i want it to zoom to the region I specified...

Comment: MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center.latitude = mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude;
    region.center.longitude = mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = 0.010;
    span.longitudeDelta = 0.010;
    region.span = span;
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

Comment: Play with the delta to see what zoom level you want.